# Jenkins sshCommand with parameters

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I work with Jenkins not long time and now need to make sshCommand with parameters to remote linux server but with parameters is not working

I put all string of command in parameter but I cannot send it with sshCommand too

Can you advise please how to send command to remote server with parameters?

Now my pipeline script is look like that:

```
String comm = 'java -jar *.jar -param '+param1+' -param '+param2
 
node {
    def remote = [:]
        remote.name = 'test'
        remote.host = '*'
        remote.user = '*'
        remote.password = '*'
        remote.allowAnyHosts = true
 
        stage('Remote SSH') {
               sshCommand remote: remote, command: ${comm}
        }
}
```